# Yii2 framework cannot login using a custom database

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Newbie and learning yii2. I have a custom database of users that I want to use as my login credential and luckily  I was able to query it, however on my public static function validatePassword($password), I am getting a Using $this when not in object context.

Here is my code

```
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
   $user = self::find()->where(['USR_USERNAME' => $username, 'USR_STATUS' => '1'])->one();
   return new static($user);
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */


public static function validatePassword($password)
{
    return $this->password === $password;
}
```

and here is the screenshot of my error. [image]

all the script was generated using gii module, so I do not know why is it producing this error, also upon watching tutorials I copy their code but not working on my end. Please help, thank you.

As requested here is the DbUser.php code

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{%RBAC_USERS}}".
 *
 * @property string $USR_UID
 * @property string $USR_USERNAME
 * @property string $USR_PASSWORD
 * @property string $USR_FIRSTNAME
 * @property string $USR_LASTNAME
 * @property string $USR_EMAIL
 * @property string $USR_DUE_DATE
 * @property string $USR_CREATE_DATE
 * @property string $USR_UPDATE_DATE
 * @property int $USR_STATUS
 * @property string $USR_AUTH_TYPE
 * @property string $UID_AUTH_SOURCE
 * @property string $USR_AUTH_USER_DN
 * @property string $USR_AUTH_SUPERVISOR_DN
 */
class DbUsers extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface

{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%RBAC_USERS}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['USR_UID', 'USR_DUE_DATE'], 'required'],
            [['USR_DUE_DATE', 'USR_CREATE_DATE', 'USR_UPDATE_DATE'], 'safe'],
            [['USR_STATUS'], 'integer'],
            [['USR_UID', 'USR_AUTH_TYPE', 'UID_AUTH_SOURCE'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['USR_USERNAME', 'USR_EMAIL'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['USR_PASSWORD'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
            [['USR_FIRSTNAME', 'USR_LASTNAME'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['USR_AUTH_USER_DN', 'USR_AUTH_SUPERVISOR_DN'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['USR_UID'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'USR_UID' => Yii::t('app', 'Uid'),
            'USR_USERNAME' => Yii::t('app', 'Username'),
            'USR_PASSWORD' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'),
        ];
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username, $password)
    {
        $user = self::find()->where(['USR_USERNAME' => $username, 'USR_STATUS' => '1'])->one();

        return $user;


    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */


    public static function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }


}
```

Here is my LoginForm.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;


/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = false;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {

        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);

        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = DbUsers::findByUsername($this->username, $this->password);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answer my own question. I added the following code in the find

```
  public static function findByUsername($username, $password)
    {
        $user = self::find()->where(['USR_USERNAME' => $username, 'USR_STATUS' => '1'])->one();

        if (hash('sha256', $password) == $user->USR_PASSWORD)
        {
            return new static($user);
        }


    }
```

now this will validate if the password is matched with the database in sha256 encryption and then on my validatePassword method I revise it to simple always return true because, on the LoginForm, they always search for the username first then check for the password validation, so If username/password is wrong it will instantly validate the user doens't exist

```
 public static function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I find yii2 hard, very hard with the lack of documentation.

Comment: It is really bad sign if you're using `sha256` for hashing passwords, especially without any salt. You should use https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security#generatePasswordHash()-detail for password management.

Comment: thanks for this mate. It's my first time using sha256

Comment: @rob006, what is the best way to add salt to this? Basically, the database is already in sha256 encryption so in my understanding just hashing it to sha256 is already ok

Answer (score 2):

In static function you can't use $this. make validatePassword() function non-static.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `$this` with static function, change to

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
   return $this->password === $password;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but now I have a new error Getting unknown property: app\models\DbUsers::password

Comment: @MiksMeister. Update your question with `Login` action code and `DbUsers` model.

Answer (score -1):

Please update your question, add a DbUsers model code.
Where the method `validatePassword()` was executed?
And of course, you cannot use $this in static method, make the method not static